# Is there a way to mass share calendars with PowerShell using office365?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365

I have a few clients on their own Office365 plans and they like to have all their calendars shared between eachother. They are very not tech savvy which leaves me to having to always login to each email account and send out shares and then accept them.

Is it possible to use powershell in Office365 and if so can you use it to mass share and accept calendar invites?

None of these clients are domain based nor do we run any exchange servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not my actual work, but "Ace Fekay" managed to make this work nicely using the follow Powershell Commands:

**To add rights to a calendar for a user, JohnDoe, and providing him “Editor” access rights:**

> Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity
>   Office.Vacation.Calendar@contoso.com:\Calendar -User
>   JohnDoe@contoso.com -AccessRights Editor

**Command to Add permissions to one Calendar for multiple users (list of users) importing a list of users in a text file and piping the command:**

> Get-Content c:\Scripts\users.txt | foreach
>   {Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity Classroom2:\calendar -User $_
>   -AccessRights Editor}
>
> Content of “users.txt:” UserOne@contoso.com UserTwo@contoso.com
>   UserThree@contoso.com UserFour@contoso.com UserFive@contoso.com
>   UserSix@contoso.com UserSeven@contoso.com UserEight@contoso.com

**Reference**: http://blogs.msmvps.com/acefekay/2015/09/13/office-365-powershell-fun-with-calendars/